# Albanian Citizenship by Naturalization: Defining Economic or Scientific Interest

Tags: immigration, citizenship, naturalization

I was looking into Albanian citizenship via naturalization and was wondering what the exact meaning of:

> Foreigners who are 18 years old, may acquire the Albanian citizenship even if they do not comply with the requirements of this Law,( with the exception of alinea 6) if the Republic of Albania has a scientific, economic, cultural or national interest.

Who would this apply to? Would starting a business be there be of economic interest? Would holding a science degree(either undergrad or graduate) be of scientific or economic interest? Any examples?

Comment: Exceptions like this are usually reserved for high-profile individuals.  For example, monarchies sometimes use an exception like this to expedite the naturalization of people marrying into the royal family. Countries sometimes naturalize athletes so they can compete on the country's behalf in the Olympics or other international competition.  Starting a business or having a degree generally helps one comply with the rules, not qualify for an exception.